# Improving the quality of my old posts?

Tags: support, edits, old-questions

I've been an active member on this site since I was 14 when I was significantly less knowledgeable in not only programming but language and communication as well, and as a result I've noticed my older questions are poorer in quality than my newer ones. Some are so bad that I'm ashamed to have posted them in the first place.

Is it possible to edit some of my older posts **without** them being bumped up? I don't want to bring needless attention to my posts while I'm fixing them, and I don't want to flood the feed with my old questions. However I really need to edit them so that they'll be clearer and more helpful for the people that might have the misfortune of stumbling upon them in the future.

If there is no such capability, what should I do instead?

Comment: The best way to take care of the old questions you're embarrassed about is to hide them in masses of new answers and questions you're proud of.

Comment: Fix 'm when someone else bumps them up. No need to fix questions that are ignored.

Comment: @MSalters: That's a circular argument, isn't it? "Fix a question only when it's already been fixed"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I find that my posts are often bumped up for other reasons, such as new answers or comments.

Comment: @MSalters: I didn't think comments triggered it. New answers okay but I think edits deserve attention for the same reason answers do: so they can be peer reviewed.

Comment: I didn't see this question until now, see mine:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294759/should-i-delete-my-answers-that-have-0-votes-and-not-marked-correct. I was thinking about deleting some of mine instead of editing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not uncommon to see older questions bumped up by even a pretty minor edit, such as adding or changing a tag. If the question appears unanswered (at least, to the OP's satisfaction), I may take a peek.

Editing without bumping up is, as far as I am aware, not possible in the current Stack Overflow model. So please be gentle towards your fellow readers: spread out your edits over a period of time. That way it is as unobtrusive as you can get.

Make sure to not accidentally change the meaning of your questions, or to invalidate them by adding something like "later I learned that .."

Comment: I totally relate. In my case, i find that my questions were based on a false premise or could have been phrased better. If I had a genie, I'd deep erase the questions I"m ashamed of asking. But oh well.  Maybe mistaken questions are a useful part of a public forum so they can remind us and other how _not_ to ask questions?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll only edit 2-3 questions every few days to keep the annoyance to a minimum

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge For the ones based on a false premise you might be able to submit close votes based off the off-topic/can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. That or something similar might be appropriate for those.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah just go ahead and edit them.

It will only bother people who have their feed on "active" (rather than "new") questions mode despite not wanting to see "active" (rather than "new") questions. That's *their* fault. :-)