# Should I delete my answers that have 0 votes and *not* marked correct?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Every once in a while, I try to clean up my StackOverflow account my removing my poor answers and **answers that had little to no attention what so ever.**

### Examples:

[Android spongy castle archive for required library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390493/android-spongy-castle-archive-for-required-library/9806879#9806879) (May 21, 2012)

[How to minimize duplication code in Android without creating Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060709/how-to-minimize-duplication-code-in-android-without-creating-objects/10060784#10060784) (April 8, 2012)

[Android : what is canonical package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14304401/android-what-is-canonical-package-name/14306309#14306309) (January 13, 2013)

### Question:

Should I remove my answers that have had no upvotes or downvotes? Possibly ones that have received little to no attention in years? It seems too late to really try and "improve" them because the original OP has most likely moved on.

### References:

Please see my "0" reputation answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/950427/jared-burrows?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=7 and https://stackoverflow.com/users/950427/jared-burrows?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=8.

Comment: Why? 0 votes is better than negative votes. Leave your valid answers over time, don't worry.

Comment: How will you know they'll remain at 0 forever?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, thanks. I was just noticing plenty of "0"s after a while.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287603/1927206. So definitely not.

Comment: In my short experience, I can tell I have already found 0-score answers that have been useful to me. So if you are sure there's no mistake in your answer you can let it live.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No.

The answers aren't wrong - in the sense that they don't have any down-votes - so they are not doing any harm.

Your alternative explanation may just be what someone needs to read to fully understand the other (accepted) answer on the question they found while searching for a solution to their problem. You never know if they have at least 15 rep they may even reward you with a belated up-vote.

Perhaps the only time you should consider deleting if yours is one of many answers that basically cover the same ground as each other.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarity. Do you find yourself deleting your older questions? As I become more experienced with software development, I have noticed the quality of my answers go up.

Comment: @JaredBurrows - I used to delete answers, but not so much these days. And yes, I see some of my early questions and answers and wince.

Comment: @JaredBurrows _"Do you find yourself deleting your older questions?"_ Most of the time I can't, because these received (upvoted) answers. I usually don't have unanswered questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Unanswered questions? I am answering questions and not getting attention on my answers.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I think Java/C# are low quality/low rewards/low attention tags now days. If you need attention - I think PHP/Phyton may be better combination... Probably could be META question even "what tag is currently top-views-per-question".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Are you suggesting I ask that question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79732/where-can-i-find-the-top-x-tags-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @JaredBurrows Good find, but it may be slightly different question (should you ask new one is open question:) )... I don't know what "popular" in particular means - number of question asked/answered is different from number of views (or average votes) per question which from my point of view indicate amount of attention that can go for individual answers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Hah are you really wanting me to ask? I am just afraid of the downvotes. Sometimes people can mark things a duplicates really quickly such as my question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294868/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-overuse-stackoverflow-for-help

Comment: @JaredBurrows if you are interested in trying to find such info I'd recommend trying to build SEDE (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) query to see if you find info that you feel helpful. Definitely don't ask question first before figuring out what you actually looking for. I'm not particularly interested in changing my set of tags C#/JS, so while theoretically interesting it is not something I'd ask myself.

Comment: Thanks. I have used this for comments in the past.

Answer (score 3):

> *not* marked correct?

If OP has not marked your answer as acceptance, it doesn't *necessarily* mean your answer is *incorrect*. It means that OP is just fine with the solution he accepted. If your answer is incorrect, you could have been downvoted as well. An answer with a zero vote is much better than an answer with downvote(s).

Also, OP might have found your solution *useful* as well, however he might not have sufficient reputation to upvote.

One more scenario comes into my mind is, there is an old question to which there is an accepted answer. However, as time progressed, you came across the question and you find something useful to add as an answer, something like you know  better way to do the same thing in newer version. Perhaps, a new feature got introduced in newer versions and it might just be the best answer for those who are on the latest version. Now, OP might not come back to mark *your* answer as accepted, however, you it is definitely useful. And you never know when someone comes across searching for a similar question and finds your answer useful, your answer would be upvoted.

There are so many topics which have an accepted answer with zero/less votes, however an unaccepted answer has higher upvotes.

Give it sometime, it doesn't harm anything to leave your zero upvoted/not accepted answers.